# IMessage can't show applicps banner after iOS 16.4

Tags: imessage, apple-appclips

It is ok before iOS 16.4 , but update 16.4(and later version),can't show appclips banner; but apple  appclips(checkcoverage.apple.com) can show normally;

how to adpater 16.4; the meta information or appclips config need config.